# Check if program is running on a list of remote computers, if not, start it (using PowerShell)

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to build what I thought would be a simple task, but it has turned more difficult than expected with lots of red text in the output window of PS ISE. :-)

I have a list of computers in a text file on my desktop.

I'd like the script to check and do two things:

1. Check if "someprogram" is running and report back on the status for that computer (some output that says something like "someprogram is not running on CVCORP-2D24DF" or something) and
2. If the program is not running, then start it.

Part of the problem has been that the program isn't a Windows program, so I don't know if it even produces a "service name" as most PS scripts I found call for.

I have the below so far. I am not at all experienced with PowerShell so I've been borrowing from other scripts I have found on the Internet and from predecessors.

At some point, once it works manually, I'd like to automate it to check for the program status every few minutes.

I appreciate any and all help I can get.

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content 'C:\users\mine\Desktop\listofcomputers.txt'    
foreach ($computer in $ComputerList)
{    
  $ServiceName = 'someprogram'
  $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName    
  while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
  {    
    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 60
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: You need to learn powershell remoting.  Read this as a start and experiment.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6

Comment: You're on the right track, but currently your script will check only your local computer for the service as many times as there are computers in the list. You should look into the `-Computer` parameter of the `*-Service` cmdlets.

Comment: Additionally, I find the best way to sanity check a script is by stepping through the process by hand in the console. Use `Get-Service` and check the output for the service you're looking for, then work on automating it locally, then implement the remote loop.